# Different Express JS Installations

Tags: node.js, express

I am just getting started with Express Js. Can someone explain the difference between

```
npm install
```

and

```
npm install -g express
```

(Installation code taken from [enter link description here](http://expressjs.com/guide.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-g` flag means install Express in your global node_modules directory. This enables you to call the `express` command anywhere. `npm install express` would be used to install the `express` library in your app, that is, you would navigate to your app directory and type `npm install express`.

I recommend that you do the following:

`npm install -g express`

Then when you navigate to your app directory, you'd type `npm link express`. This symlinks to the global express install.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes it does thanks a lot. I do have a follow up though. Why would I need express as a global module? Isn't is only useful in node as a framework?

Comment: So you can run the `express` command.

Comment: I do not recommend using global (-g). When you have multiple apps using Express and you need to upgrade Express (or any other npm module for that matter) you will upgrade it for all of your apps. This requires retesting of all your apps. There are exceptions to the rule. For some command line utils it is handy to use -g so you can access it globally.

Comment: Meh, if that becomes an issue, you can then just `npm install express` in your app directory instead of `npm link express`. But you'll want to `npm install -g express` so that the `express` command is in your path.

Comment: @BartRiemens from what I understand you can have both. Use the npm link express to use the global module or npm install to just install express in the current application

Comment: @thearchitect that is correct.

Comment: @thearchitect True! Just want to warn about linking multiple projects to global and then start updating your global modules. As a discipline I would recommend to keep the modules local as part of your project. This prevents surprises in the future.

Comment: You can also run binaries from locally installed modules using `./node_modules/.bin`, e.g. `./node_modules/.bin/express`. For apps like Express where you're only likely to run it once or very seldomly, I find little value in installing it globally.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install express
```

will create a folder called node_modules in your current folder and install express in it.

```
npm install -g express
```

will install express on you system in some place like /usr/local/lib/node_modules

The reason why you want a global install of Express or supervisor for example, is to use the bin tool.

The bin tool of express generate a template project which is super useful.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @JP Richardson and @3on indicated regarding **npm install express** and **npm -g  install express**, when you run **npm install** (without express or -g express) npm will read the package.json file in the current directory and install (locally) the dependencies listed in package.json

This is the reason the example in http://expressjs.com/guide.html works. The package.json that it asks you to create, indicates Express 3.x as a dependency and npm will know how to download it and install it.

Comment: In addition you can do the same with npm install -g to install modules from package.json globally